# How to test PNP using JEST?

Tags: spfx, pnp, pnpjs

Is there any way to mock the context of the webpart since i need it to be able to make a request through pnp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import two typescript classes from SPFx, Enviroment and EnviromentType:

```
import { Environment, EnvironmentType } from "@microsoft/sp-core-library";
```

so you can identify the enviroment:

```
if (Environment.type == EnvironmentType.SharePoint || 
    Environment.type == EnvironmentType.ClassicSharePoint) {
    // use sp context and pnp calls...
} else {
    // mock data...
}
```

Then you should define two classes that implement the same interface, one class with pnp calls and the other with functions that return mock data.

Jest has [built-in support for mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api), but [Sinon.js](https://sinonjs.org/) could be a better option.